# Cannot plot a jquery pie-chart code inside other jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to plot pie chart by using the data that i got from GET request. Here is the code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "myurl",
          success: function(data){ 
              //$('#data').text(data);

              var json_obj = data.body;
              

              console.log(json_obj);
              
              var sedans = 0;
              var SUVs = 0;
              
              for (var key of Object.keys(json_obj)) {
                console.log("key ",key);
                console.log(json_obj[key]["vehicle_model"]);
                var formatModel = json_obj[key]["vehicle_model"].split("-");
                if(formatModel[1] == "Sedan"){
                  sedans++;
                }else if(formatModel[1] == "SUV"){
                  SUVs++;
                }
              }

              console.log("suvs ",SUVs);
              console.log("sedans ",sedans);
              var totalVehicles = sedans+SUVs;
              console.log("total vehicles",totalVehicles);
              sedansPercentage = sedans*100/totalVehicles;
              SUVsPercentage = SUVs*100/totalVehicles;
              console.log("Sedans %", sedansPercentage);
              console.log("SUV %", SUVsPercentage);

              console.log("sedanspe", sedansPercentage);
              var data_pie = [
                {"name" : "Sedan", "hvalue" : sedansPercentage, "color": "brown" },
                {"name" : "SUV", "hvalue" : SUVsPercentage, "color": "gray" } 
              ];

              console.log("data pie", data_pie)
              $(".exp").donutpie();
              $(".exp").donutpie('update', data_pie);
              $(".exp").donutpie({
                radius: 240,
                tooltip : true,
                tooltipClass : "donut-pie-tooltip-bubble"
              });
          },
          error: function(){
            alert("There was an error.");
          },
        });

      });
```

Whenever I use the piece of the code below outside the $(document).ready function it works properly. But as soon as I nest it in some any other jquery function it stops working.

```
var data_pie = [
                {"name" : "Sedan", "hvalue" : sedansPercentage, "color": "brown" },
                {"name" : "SUV", "hvalue" : SUVsPercentage, "color": "gray" } 
              ];

              console.log("data pie", data_pie)
              $(".exp").donutpie();
              $(".exp").donutpie('update', data_pie);
              $(".exp").donutpie({
                radius: 240,
                tooltip : true,
                tooltipClass : "donut-pie-tooltip-bubble"
              });
```

How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is a very difficult task. So I found other simpler way and decided to use pure javascript without jquery for my pie chart so i can use it along with get request.

```
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/8.0.1/anychart-core.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/8.0.1/anychart-pie.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "my url",
          success: function(data){ 
              //$('#data').text(data);

              var json_obj = data.body;
            

              console.log("placeholder" ,data);
              
              var sedans = 0;
              var SUVs = 0;
              
              for (var key of Object.keys(json_obj)) {
                console.log("key ",key);
                console.log(json_obj[key]["vehicle_model"]);
                var formatModel = json_obj[key]["vehicle_model"].split("-");
                if(formatModel[1] == "Sedan"){
                  sedans++;
                }else if(formatModel[1] == "SUV"){
                  SUVs++;
                }
              }

              console.log("suvs ",SUVs);
              console.log("sedans ",sedans);
              var totalVehicles = sedans+SUVs;
              console.log("total vehicles",totalVehicles);
              sedansPercentage = sedans*100/totalVehicles;
              SUVsPercentage = SUVs*100/totalVehicles;
              console.log("Sedans %", sedansPercentage);
              console.log("SUV %", SUVsPercentage);

              console.log("sedanspe", sedansPercentage);
              
              anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {

              // set the data
              var data = [
                  {x: "SUVs", value: SUVs},
                  {x: "Sedan", value: sedans}
              ];

              // create the chart
              var chart = anychart.pie();

              // set the chart title
              chart.title("SEDAN/SUV ratio");

              // add the data
              chart.data(data);

              // display the chart in the container
              chart.container('container');
              chart.draw();

              });
              
          },
          error: function(){
            alert("There was an error.");
          },
        });

        

      });
```

CSS

```
#container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```